# Добавление атрибута к тегу

Tags: javascript

```
function addRow(id){
    var name = document.getElementById('nameid').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('priceid').value;
    var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    var row = document.createElement("TR");

    tbody.appendChild(row);

    var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
    var td2 = document.createElement("TD");

    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    td1.innerHTML = name;
    td2.innerHTML = price;
}
```

Вопрос в том как добавить к ряду row атрибут onclick

Comment: Задача заключается в копировании строки из таблицы 1 в таблицу 2 по клику на строку, причем строка изначально получена через форму на странице. При вставке row.addEventListener("click", function() { /* */ }); к сожалению ругается и все равно создает <tr></tr>

Comment: Событие нужно повесить после создания и вывода тегов `tr`

Comment: А как тогда выбрать элемент под мышкой ? ну т.е. допустим я создал полностью таблицу; и пишу что то типа document.getElementById/tag/class, а ничего из этого то нету

Comment: с помощью `this`. он вернет нажатый элемент.

Comment: В гугле вроде как не забанен, но ... Ничего кроме jquarry по этому вопросу не нахожу :( Не могли бы вы привести хотя бы примерный код, к чему ,так сказать, стремится ?

Answer (score 1):

```
row.addEventListener("click", function() { /* */ });
```